# Return array with CSS query in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer

I am trying to get an array of strings from a website with puppeteer.

I have the CSS Selector `td[class*="myClass"]` which selects all the elements I want, and I then want to get the `.innerText` of every one of them.

So with that selector I know I can select 20 elements (I have tested this with `<style> td[class*="myClass"] {background: red}</style>`).

I am trying to get an array of their `.innerText` with:

```
console.log(await page.$eval('td[class*="myClass"]', element => element.innerText));
```

however this returns only the first element.

Does anyone know how I can select all the 20 elements and not only the first one?

Thank you!

Comment: try `page.$$eval` instead of `page.$eval`

Comment: @B12Toaster Thank you for your answer. For some reason I get `undefined` when I add a second $.

Comment: maybe you are using an old puppeteer version? see https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args

Comment: When I do:
`await page.$$eval('td[class*="good_to_col"]', element => element.length)`
I get 20. When I do:
`await page.$$eval('td[class*="good_to_col"]', element => element.innerText)`
I get undefined! When I do:
`await page.$$eval('td[class*="good_to_col"]', element => element)`
I get an array of 20 empty items. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: yes, when using $$eval your function is being passed an array as argument, that's your mistake I think. So you try to invoke `innerText` on an array which of course does not exist. Instead try `await page.$$eval('td[class*="good_to_col"]', elements => elements.map(e => e.innerText))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
await page.$$eval('td[class*="good_to_col"]', element => element.innerText);
```

An array doesn't have `innerText` property. If you want to return an array of 20 innerTexts, you need to map it:

```js
await page.$$eval('td[class*="good_to_col"]', elements => elements.map(
    element => element.innerText)
);
```

It's mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args).

Comment: Thank you! This worked great! I did read the docs but didn't understand what that mapping is at all. Another solution I just found is `await page.evaluate(() => 
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td[class*="myClass"]'), e => e.innerText));`

Comment: You can read up on map here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

For convenience/semantic reasons, Puppeteer provides you with two different eval functions.

[page.$eval()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) runs `document.querySelector` and, thus, only passes the first element it finds to your `pageFunction`.

[page.$$eval()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) internally runs `document.querySelectorAll` and, thus, passes multiple elements to your `pageFunction` and returns an array.

**A word of caution:**
Some people may wrongfully assume, the second argument passed to `$$eval` is an iterator function that is invoked for each result of the `css-selector`. However, a bit counter-intuitively, `$$eval` passes an **array** as argument to your function, so any mapping needs to be done on this array. So referring to the OP, instead of `page.$$eval('td[class*="good_to_col"]', element => element.innerText)` use `page.$$eval('td[class*="good_to_col"]', elements => elements.map(e => e.innerText))` and it shall work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

The html elements look like this:

`<td class="myClass otherClass">no</td>`

When I $$eval `element => element.length` I get 20, so it correctly finds the 20 elements I want. However it returns undefined when I do `element => element.innerText`, and it returns an empty array with 20 items if I do `element => element`

Comment: yeah, can be tricky, I answered you below your question, will add this to my answer since this is often missed.

Comment: Legend! Thank you for the context.